# How to change account in GitBash

Tags: git, logout, account

i would like to change my account in gitbash. The usual

1.delete credentials via windows-credential manager **or**

```
 $ git credential-manager delete https://github.com
```

**Issue:** Doesn't work / doesn't do anything

**Question:** `$ git config -l` delievers an `user.email` which  i don't want to use / i.e. want to logout from the present account an login into a new one. How do i do that?

Comment: `user.name`/`user.email` have nothing with accounts and credentials.

Comment: When adding an commit it is going to come from github account with this `user.email`

Comment: Yes, but it's not related to accounts, identification, authorization, passwords. You can push commits with any name and any email, for example, commits from your collaborators.

Comment: I think what @Roman is asking about is how to change their method of credential authorization (i.e., `credential.helper`). Is that correct?

Comment: The point is, right now when commiting a file to a repository it is being done from account1, that is also mentioned in `git config -l`, i do however want it to be account2, all the solutions till right now have not been effective.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018 "delete" is deprecated, use reject instead.

```
git credential-manager reject <url>
```

OR

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Next time when you do a git action such as clone, push, pull etc the username & password prompt will appear for you to enter the new credentials you want to use.

Comment: didn't work, the very same account does the commit the very same config is being shown, despite also enetering a new account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to directly change the *username/email* in the config, in order to commit from a **another account**.

```
$ git config --global user.name "GithubUsername"

$ git config --global user.email "Email"
```